# Converting a char array into an structure similar to int argc and char** argv

Tags: c, string, command-line, char, arguments

I have read a text line from a file, and I need to convert it to an structure similar to main function arguments. For example if the char array is `char* text="There are books in the library."` and I have below structure definition:

```
struct mystruct{
   int argc;
   char** argv;
};
```

if I have `struct mystruct a`, with the function `foo(a, text)` I end up with `a.argc` equal to 6, `a.argv[0]` equal to *There*, `a.argv[1]` equal to *are*, ... .

Is there any function or library in C I can use for this purpose? Since this conversion is done automatically for input arguments when we execute C main function.

Comment: The shell does the splitting and passes the split arguments to the `exec*()` functions which relay the split arguments to the called main program.  So, your best bet may be looking at the code of someone else's shell.  It's not dreadfully hard to write; if you record an `int argmax;` in the structure, you can even make it reasonably efficient.

Comment: If you make it `char[] text = ...` then you could go through the string with `strtok` and save the resulting pointers. (Maybe this is the first time I ever recommended strtok...)

Comment: I think *argv[] will work

Comment: You can also use `sscanf` to read strings delimited by whitespace in the input and then use `strdup` to duplicate the strings.

Comment: The conversion from command line arguments to `argc` and `argv` is done by the execution environment. There are no library functions to create that. However, as @MattMcNabb suggested, you can write a function to construct a `mystruct` given `text` using `strtok` and `malloc`. Shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `strtok` to do this split, like this:

```
struct split_result {
    int cnt;
    char *buf;
    char **strs;
};

int
split(const char *str, struct split_result *rst)
{
    int idx, str_num;
    char *buf, *sep, **strs;

    buf = strdup(str);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        perror("strdup");
        return -1;
    }

    str_num = 1;
    strs = malloc(str_num * sizeof(char *));
    if (strs == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        return -1;
    }

    sep = " \t";
    idx = 0;
    for (strs[idx] = strtok(buf, sep);
         strs[idx];
         strs[idx] = strtok(NULL, sep))
    {
        idx++;
        if (idx >= str_num) {
            str_num += 10;
            strs = realloc(strs, str_num * sizeof(char *));
            if (strs == NULL) {
                perror("realloc");
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    rst->cnt = idx;
    rst->strs = strs;
    rst->buf = buf;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is a test program and its output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct split_result {
    int cnt;
    char *buf;
    char **strs;
};

int
split(const char *str, struct split_result *rst)
{
    int idx, str_num;
    char *buf, *sep, **strs;

    buf = strdup(str);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        perror("strdup");
        return -1;
    }

    str_num = 1;
    strs = malloc(str_num * sizeof(char *));
    if (strs == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        return -1;
    }

    sep = " \t";
    idx = 0;
    for (strs[idx] = strtok(buf, sep);
         strs[idx];
         strs[idx] = strtok(NULL, sep))
    {
        idx++;
        if (idx >= str_num) {
            str_num += 10;
            strs = realloc(strs, str_num * sizeof(char *));
            if (strs == NULL) {
                perror("realloc");
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    rst->cnt = idx;
    rst->strs = strs;
    rst->buf = buf;

    return 0;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    struct split_result rst;
    const char *msg[] = {
        "",
        " One",
        " One  Two",
        " One  Two Tree  ",
        "There are books in the library.",
        NULL,
    };

    for (i = 0; msg[i]; i++) {
        if (split(msg[i], &rst) < 0) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("msg[%d] = >>%s<<\n", i, msg[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < rst.cnt; j++) {
            printf("cnt = %d: |%s|\n", j, rst.strs[j]);
        }

        free(rst.strs);
        free(rst.buf);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
msg[0] = >><<
msg[1] = >> One<<
cnt = 0: |One|
msg[2] = >> One  Two<<
cnt = 0: |One|
cnt = 1: |Two|
msg[3] = >> One  Two Tree  <<
cnt = 0: |One|
cnt = 1: |Two|
cnt = 2: |Tree|
msg[4] = >>There are books in the library.<<
cnt = 0: |There|
cnt = 1: |are|
cnt = 2: |books|
cnt = 3: |in|
cnt = 4: |the|
cnt = 5: |library.|
```

Comment: If `realloc` fails, then it returns `NULL` which is assigned to `strs`. This will lose handle on the previously allocated memory causing memory leak. You should use a temporary variable to save `strs` before calling `realloc`.

Comment: @ajay If `realloc()` failed, then `split()` will return `-1` and the program will terminate. However, it is possible to add proper free statements before all those `return -1;` in this `split()` so when it returns `-1`, any memory regions it dynamically allocated are freed.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the file have a number that specifies the number of arguments. if that is the case then create a loop and read each string until you encounter a delimiter ( again, assuming that you were told there is one ). If you don't have "the" number of arguments then add a member of type unsigned, in your struct, to keep track of the number of words read.
You really don't need to create a split_function, but it doesn't hurt if you decided to create one :)